# Scan barcode from any distance

Tags: google-glass, barcode-scanner, google-gdk

I have to start work with bar code scanning in Google Glass. I am quite new to it and don't have much experience about Google glass. I got a working library **[BarcodeEye](https://github.com/BarcodeEye/BarcodeEye)**. But I'm little bit confused as I have no device right now.  Does it scan the bar code from any distance OR does it require any specific size of bar code to get detected??

My requirement is to scan the bar code from approximately 5-7 feet distance.

So will this library detect the bar code from this distance or will I need to zoom or some other logic to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BarCode Fragment Lib V2](https://code.google.com/p/barcodefraglibv2/) Have tested this to work with Glass.

Comment: will it fulfill my requirement ??

Comment: **My requirement is to scan the bar code from approximately 5-7 feet distance.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try the early version of the well-known Barcode Scanner app, ported to Glass, from the main project:

- https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/glass
- https://github.com/zxing/zxing/releases/tag/BSGlass-0.2.0

5-7 feet is possible, but the barcode would have to be reasonably large. Try it and see.

Comment: It might not be the large enough to detect :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use ZXING library for GoogleGlass for Scanning Barcode.

follow below steps

1.download `Zxing` source code from 
 [This Link](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

2.import this project and mark it as library.

3.In your Google Glass project add downloaded `ZXING` project as library and Use below code in your `MainActivity`

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
 integrator.initiateScan();
```

and don't forget to add `CaptureActivity` of Library project  in `Manifest`.